# Link canonical se duplica cuando agrego Google Tag Manager

Tags: next.js

> **PROBLEMA:** Cuando agrego Google Tag Manager a mi proyecto, la etiqueta `<link href="https://www.mywebsite.com/" rel="canonical">` se duplica

Tengo un codigo que no es mio y me confunde un poco, ya que tengo dos componentes con el nombre `<Head/>`, uno personalizado y el de next.js

En el Layout de mi App tengo el head personalizado, que hace uso de `NextHead` y es donde se cargan los metadatos. Tanto la etiqueta canonical como las demas funcionan correctamente.

```
<NextHead>
  ...
  <link
    href={canonical}
    rel="canonical"
  />
  {children}
</NextHead>
```

El problema es cuando agrego GTM a mi `_document`. GTM funciona de perlas, pero el problema es que vuelve a agregar la etiqueta `<link href="https://www.mywebsite.com/" rel="canonical">` al final de la etiqueta `<head>` que renderiza el navegador.

Lo mas extraño de todo es que si yo elimino la etiqueta canonical de mi componente `<Head/>` personalizado (fue lo que intenté pensando que no era necesario agregar la etiqueta, ya que la generaba GTM), no aparece en el navegador.

En `_document.js` tengo esto:

```
import Document, {
  Head, Html, Main, NextScript
} from "next/document";
import Script from "next/script";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return {
      ...initialProps,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en-US">
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;600;700;900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
          <Script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
          })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXX');`,
            }}
            id="google-tag-manager"
            strategy="afterInteractive"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <noscript>
            <iframe
              height="0"
              src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX"
              style={{
                display: "none",
                visibility: "hidden",
              }}
              width="0"
            />
          </noscript>
          <div id="nprogress-container" />
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Alguien sabe por qué esta pasando esto?

Capaz que falta codigo o contexto, de ser asi me lo dejan en los comentarios. Muchas gracias.